# infrastructure elements in a 50 peoplebranch office

Tags: small-business

I am a programmer by profession. I have been asked by a friend of mine to help set up  open source based network infrastructure elements for his company's branch office that may have up to 50 people.  Since I do not have practical experience in this, I tried looking up guides that helped in understanding and setting up infrastructure for small offices. However I could not find any such guide. As I understand, I need to have a router ( possibly from vyatta),  a firewall(iptables?), switches (vyatta again), openvpn for remote access. monitoring tools (nagios)
I did find this http://www.zentyal.org/ but not sure if this is useful.
This was interesteding but it comes laterhttp://tboxmy.blogspot.com/2010/02/why-would-small-office-switch-to-open.html.

I am hoping that hte community here will be able to provide some pointers.
Thanks

Comment: I strongly caution you and your friend against going on some holy vendetta against commercial solutions. While the F/OSS community certainly has some winners available, the CapEx of a network is rarely a significant portion of the TCO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've taken the first step down the wrong path - i.e. defining the solution before defining the problem.

What services do you need to provide to this branch office? Enumerate those, then search for a solution.